# Intellij "Create Pull Request" Description field unable to add new line

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in Intellij (v2017.2) to add a new line in the "Create pull request" "Description" field. I've tried a few combination of control + enter; command + enter; alt + enter. None of which have worked. I believe adding a new line wasn't an issue in previous builds of intellij.

[image]

Update:
Dmitriy Smirnov was correct this issue was caused by a third party plugin in my case "JSON Formatter" Version: 0.3.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enter` works fine for me. And `Ctrl+Enter` triggers OK.
AFAIK, there is no any specific setting for this.

Does it work if you paste a text with a line break?
Are there any other places where Enter does not work?
Are there any errors in the logs?

Some third-party plugins might affect this, so you could try disabling them if any.